# Spring Singleton scope and Singleton pattern

Tags: spring, spring-boot, singleton, osgi

So, basically, I have a single Spring Boot web application which starts and uses OSGI container inside of it. I thought I would use a single instance of OSGI container per web application and made the class, which contains and serves OSGI context using a singleton pattern.

Would it be better to use a Bean for OSGI container with singleton scope or keep it the way it is?

Comment: Actually the default of creation object is singleton

Comment: @ShaabanEbrahim, I know the default is singleton. I only want to know if it would be okay to use bean singleton instead of real singleton patterned object.

Comment: if you can implement singleton design pattern like spring i think it will not  be very big difference